# Why did Guru come back to life?

Tags: dragon-ball

During the Namek Saga of Dragon Ball Z, the first wish to Porunga was to bring Piccolo back, next was teleport him to Namek but before the third wish could be granted Guru died making the Namekian Dragonballs useless.

After Freeza sets Namek to explode the Dragonballs bad been collected on earth (now that Kami was back) and the wish made to Shenron was to *"Bring back everyone who had been killed by Freeza"*. after this the Namekian Dragonballs come back and Dende uses the final wish to teleport everyone except Freeza and Goku to earth.

what i don't get is how Guru was resurrected when the wish to Shenron was to bring everyone Freeza had killed back to life, why was Guru brought back to life even though he wasn't killed by Freeza?

Comment: I've also ask that myself long time ago. When I look at this question and look back, I wonder if that exact wish should also mean that *everyone's* who had been killed by Freeza should be alive after that (basically, why bardok and all the other saiyans didn't brought to life).

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Time limit. Specifically mentioned in the episode as I recall. A restriction specifically added in the writing so he wouldn't restore all those people (likely to the vacuum where their destroyed planet was) and create this very problem.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Not according to this: http://youtu.be/ACCSYH37D_A?t=19m25s

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Watch it again. Around 5:50 Kami and King Kai are discussing the wish, and Kami clearly says it will only go back a year at most.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy umm... I guess you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all explained by King Kai during the Freeza Saga in **chapter 321**.

[image: enter image description here!]

King Kai asks Kami whether people that had died from old age could be revived, to which the answer was negative. So then he asks whether people that had indirectly died by an evil person could be revived, to which the answer was positive.

Kami replied positive, saying that even though it'd be a first-time case, he'd believe it would be possible to revive those that indirectly died. They would then remain alive for the duration of time their life was shortened by.

> King Kai: What if they were confronted by an evil person, and, indirectly though it may be, their death was hastened, even a little bit...?
>   Kami: I believe they would remain alive for the duration of time their life was shortened by...

Knowing this, King Kai asked not only to bring back those killed by Freeza himself, but also by his henchman (Eg: which would include Vegeta).

Answer (score 1):

It's true that Grand Elder Guru was not **directly** killed by Freeza's hands, but his death was someway caused by Freeza, according to [Dragon Ball Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Elder_Guru):

> He dies before Frieza is defeated, of a combination of a broken heart
>   and stress (both brought on from repeatedly sensing his children's
>   deaths at the hands of Frieza's minions).

So the way Freeza and his minions decimated his race caused his death.
So the wish "Bring back everyone who had been killed by Freeza" involves a lot more cases than only the ones that died from Freeza's hands. It also involves the ones killed **indirectly** by his acts.

To confirm this, the Wiki also says:

> King Kai chooses to revive him and all the other victims of Frieza's
>   army with the Earth's Dragon Balls so the Namekian dragon, Porunga,
>   would be brought back. The wish revives Elder Guru because Frieza's
>   murder of the Namekians caused Guru to die of grief.

Comment: Moreover, the episode (in the dub at least) goes to great lengths to explain King Kai's plan, and that his rationale was that Guru died of the grief rather than his age. Kami thinks hard to figure out if it is possible, and tentatively agrees it is possible but a long shot. The dragon groans about it being a difficult wish. And then King Kai is anxiously trying to figure out if Guru was restored once the dragon started granting the wish. There was really no ambiguity in how this worked.

Answer (score 0):

They actually address this in the anime.  Guru died from a broken heart due to Frieza's genocide of his people and utter destruction of his home planet.  So technically, Frieza did kill guru, even though it wasn't directly, he was still responsible.